# Is the callID in call telephony and record id in address book same in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number, core-telephony

Can i fetch phone number from callID from core telephony framework ?
Is the  callID in call telephony and record id in address book same in iphone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the phone number is not retrievable from the callID, using the Core Telephony framework.

No, the callID and recordID are not the same.